# HDD Partition Delete Using Linux Bootable Disc: Manually From Shell/ CUI Environment

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, delete

Please let me know what are the commands and their syntax for

1) display all partitions from shell

2) delete any/ all partition from shell

Requirement/ Situation:

In some machine there was Ubuntu installed on it. After that they have tried windows. Now it is showing no space in HDD when trying to install windows again. So, it is required to delete all the partitions using "Linux Startup Disc" manually to retrieve all the partitions occupied by Linux.

So, I need to know the commands that can be executed from the shell.

Comment: Why dont you just use the windows formatting tool that runs when you install windows, it can modify and remove partitions

Comment: Using Windows Disc it can't find any space; all occupied by Linux

Comment: So why not delete it ?

Comment: I want to delete the partition but using windows Disc it is not tracable; so the question...

Comment: OK then the answer below works or if you have a ubuntu live CD or USB boot to try Ubuntu and run Gparted

Comment: Ok, I will try. Then i will report back. Thaks.

Comment: Still I egar to know the manual/ CUI commands to handle partitions.

Comment: I added a link to his answer to show you all commands for man fdisk this is what you are looking for. May need to wait for it to be peer reviewed,before you can see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your not too confident in the CLI. Try Gparted Live. It boots to a GUI.

http://gparted.org/download.php

Otherwise start looking at `man fdisk`

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man8/fdisk.8.html